# ¿Cómo puedo informarle al usuario si el número que ha ingresado en un campo es múltiplo de dos números simultáneamente utilizando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, condiciones, botón, onclick

¡Hola! Tengo una duda concreta con respecto a mi código JavaScript. Estoy utilizando la librería jQuery e intento informarle al usuario si el número que ha ingresado es múltiplo de 7 y 3 simultáneamente. Si no es así, entonces lo contrario, pero mi código no logra darme la información correcta.

Aquí les muestro lo básico que logré hacer hasta ahora:

```
$("#btnValor").click(mostrarMultiplos);

let valor;
let resto1 = valor / 7;
let resto2 = valor / 3;

function mostrarMultiplos(){
    valor = Number($("#valor1").val());
    if(resto1 === 0 && resto2 === 0){
        alert("múltiplo de 7 y 3");
    }else{
        alert("no múltiplo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Number** es una clase, no es una función, deberías hacer esto:

```
valor = parseFloat($("#valor1").val());
```

En vez de:

```
Number($("#valor1").val());
```

Tambien se podría usar parseInt:

```
valor = parseInt($("#valor1").val());
```

Ahora bien, para resolver el problema, te dare una pequeña introducción a un operador llamado residuo:

```
%
```

Si, se que es el simbolo de porcentaje que muchos conocemos, pero esa no es su función en javascript, la función del simbolo residuo (%), es exactamente esa, determinar cuanto es el residuo de una division entre un numero y otro, por ejemplo si tu divides:

```js
console.log(4 % 3);
```

El resultado es 1, debido a que 3 cabe solo una vez en 4, y le falta solo **1** para llegar a ser 4, habiendo entendido esto, se puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
$("#btnValor").click(mostrarMultiplos);
let valor;

function mostrarMultiplos(){
    valor = parseFloat($("#valor1").val());

    if(valor % 7 === 0 && valor % 3 === 0){
        alert("múltiplo de 7 y 3");
    }else{
        alert("no múltiplo");
    }

}
```

Cuando decimos:

```
valor % 7 === 0 && valor % 3 === 0
```

Lo que estamos preguntando es si el valor que digito el usuario es divisible exactamente por 7 y por 4 a la vez, en cuyo caso, la operacion `x % 7` será igual a `0` y `x % 3` será igual a cero.

Comment: Prueba esto: `let numero = "10"
typeof numero
"string"
let resultado = Number(numero)
typeof resultado
"number"`

Comment: Si, lo acabo de ver en tu snippet, interesante... aunque hay una ligera diferencia entre crear un numero usando la clase, y parsear el numero.

Comment: Aunque tambien lo decia, por que parece que se estaba confundiendo anteriormente a java con javascript, por eso lo decía.

Answer (score 0):

Para calcular el módulo(resto) tienes que usar el operador `%`.

Los valores de resto no puedes calcularlos antes porque aun no tienes el valor que hay en la caja `#valor1`. Por eso, debes calcular dichos valores en la función que se ejecuta en en `click` es donde lees el valor de la caja. 
Y no estas calculando el modulo sino la división, tienes que entender que son dos operaciones distintas.

```
let resto1 = valor / 7;
let resto2 = valor / 3;
```

Aquí te dejo una solución.

```js
$("#btnValor").click(mostrarMultiplos);

let valor;

function mostrarMultiplos(){
    valor = Number($("#valor1").val());
    const resto1 = valor % 7;
    const resto2 = valor % 3;
    if(resto1 === 0 && resto2 === 0){
        alert("múltiplo de 7 y 3");
    }else{
        alert("no múltiplo");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="valor1"/>

<button id="btnValor" >multiplo?</button>
```